# Does an immersed curve in general position has finite self-intersections?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, intersection-theory

This problem comes from Hirsch's differential topology in page 67.

> "Generically" a $C^1$ immersion $S^1\to \mathbb{R}^2$ has only a finite number of crossing points.

Then I want to ask if in general a $C^1$ immersion $I\to M$, where $I$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R^1}$ and $M$ is a $C^1$ manifold, has finite self-intersections.

Intuitively, since the curve is $C^1$, it can not change drastically in a small enough neighborhood, then we can perturbate it a little near the limit points of self-intersections to obtain a immersed curve with finite self-intersections. I don't know how to prove it rigorously, even for the case $I\to \mathbb{R}^2$. Since this problem occurs in chapter 3,  the proof may need transversality theorems.

Comment: Did you solve the problem about maps of the circle? The proof for the interval is exactly the same. The point is that a compact 1-dimensional manifold is a finite set.

Comment: No, I didn't.  I know that a compact 0-manifold is a finite set. However, I have no idea how to approximate an immersed curve by another immersed curve such that its self-intersections is compact. The curve can be covered by coordinate charts, then essentially we need to solve the problem in $\mathbb{R}^n$  .

Comment: If $I$ is an open interval, then the curve could have infinitely many intersections. If also that $M$ is two dimensional, then the intersection cannot be perturbed away.